# Best choice of uploading files into S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have to upload video files into an S3 bucket from my React web application. I am currently developing a simple react application and from this application, I am trying to upload video files into an S3 bucket so I have decided two approaches for implementing the uploading part.

**1) Amazon EC2 instance:** From the front-end, I am hitting the API and the server is running in the Amazon EC2 instance. So I can upload the files into S3 bucket from the ec2 instance.

**2) Amazon API Gateway + Lambda:** I am directly sending the local files into an S3 bucket through API + Lambda function by calling the https URL with data.

But I am not happy with these two methods because both are more costly. I have to upload files into an S3 bucket, and the files are more than 200MB. I don't know I can optimize this uploading process. Video uploading part is necessary for my application and I should be very careful to do this part and also I have to increase the performance and cost-effective.

If someone knows any solution please share with me, I will be very helpful for me to continue my process.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can directly upload files from your react app to s3 using aws javascript sdk and cognito identity pools and for the optimization part you can use AWS multipart upload capability to upload file in multiple parts I'm providing links to read about it further

[AWS javascript upload image example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-photo-album.html)

[cognito identity pools](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/using-amazon-cognito-user-identity-pools-javascript-examples.html)

[multipart upload to S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/uploadobjusingmpu.html)

also consider a look at aws managed upload made for javascript sdk

[aws managed upload javascript](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3/ManagedUpload.html)

Comment: Thanks, varnit. But Javascript is not available in multipart upload approach. It has Java, .NET, PHP and Ruby. So How can I import this approach into my React application? Correct me If I am wrong.

Comment: you can use rest api for multipart upload https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingRESTAPImpUpload.html

Comment: yeah but it looks something like terminal commands. Sorry, I am new to multipart upload method and how can I use these commands inside my react code?

Comment: you can use managed upload i have pasted the link above and those are not terminal commands these are examples of rest requests you can use fetch() function in react to make these requests

Comment: Thanks, varnit. If I want to access s3 bucket only for authenticated users means then how to do that?

Comment: aws cognito provide both options

Comment: for authenticated user and for unauthenticated users

Comment: is your issue solved, if yes please accept the answer or upvote it if you like it

Answer (score 1):

In order to bypass the EC2, you can use a pre-authenticated [POST](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingHTTPPOST.html) request to directly upload you content from the browser to the S3 bucket.

Comment: Sorry, I am not clear. How to implement this approach with my react application. any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Goal: Download videos from a URL and upload them to an AWS S3 bucket using a cloud solution. Perform this process for bulk videos (800+ videos). Advantages include avoiding local network issues and achieving speeds of 6+ Mbps during download and upload.

**Steps to Upload Video to S3 Bucket from Ubuntu AWS EC2:**

Prepare Excel with Command Formulas:

Download file command

```
youtube-dl -o {{FileName}} {{DownloadURL}}
```

Upload command

```
aws s3 cp {{FileName}} {{awss3path}}
```

Remove file command

```
rm {{FileName}}
```

Examples:

```
Download command
youtube-dl -o 00bb3af108f31fb1113d226a33f092e5_86_30_Min_The_STRIDE.mp4 https://bcbolt446c5271-a.akamaihd.net/media/v1/pmp4/static/clear/6276211635001/237b0d28-b840-4ba1-8a04-a0841451e325/eda439a9-ac78-4523-a29f-3f2d7b5fa0cb/main.mp4?akamai_token=exp=1690627940~acl=/media/v1/pmp4/static/clear/6276211635001/237b0d28-b840-4ba1-8a04-a0841451e325/eda439a9-ac78-4523-a29f-3f2d7b5fa0cb/main.mp4*~hmac=890da059cf0f4cc9438eb1bb157d0503dbcf514c85c8c54d7e63fd1b5301bd15
```

Upload command

```
aws s3 cp 00bb3af108f31fb1113d226a33f092e5_86_30_Min_The_STRIDE.mp4 s3://content-intake-fod247/Content/
```

Remove file

```
rm 00bb3af108f31fb1113d226a33f092e5_86_30_Min_The_STRIDE.mp4
```

Combine Commands into Single Line:.
Add a fourth column in Excel to combine all commands into a single line. Include an extra check to avoid downloading if the file already exists in S3.

```
if aws s3 ls {{s3FilePath}}; then
    echo "File exists";
else
    youtube-dl -o {{FileName}} {{DownloadURL}};
    aws s3 cp {{FileName}} {{awss3path}};
    rm {{FileName}};
fi
```

Example:

```
if aws s3 ls s3://content-intake-fod247/Content/00bb3af108f31fb1113d226a33f092e5_86_30_Min_The_STRIDE.mp4; then echo "File exists"; else youtube-dl -o 00bb3af108f31fb1113d226a33f092e5_86_30_Min_The_STRIDE.mp4 https://bcbolt446c5271-a.akamaihd.net/media/v1/pmp4/static/clear/6276211635001/237b0d28-b840-4ba1-8a04-a0841451e325/eda439a9-ac78-4523-a29f-3f2d7b5fa0cb/main.mp4?akamai_token=exp=1690627940~acl=/media/v1/pmp4/static/clear/6276211635001/237b0d28-b840-4ba1-8a04-a0841451e325/eda439a9-ac78-4523-a29f-3f2d7b5fa0cb/main.mp4*~hmac=890da059cf0f4cc9438eb1bb157d0503dbcf514c85c8c54d7e63fd1b5301bd15; aws s3 cp 00bb3af108f31fb1113d226a33f092e5_86_30_Min_The_STRIDE.mp4 s3://content-intake-fod247/Content/; rm 00bb3af108f31fb1113d226a33f092e5_86_30_Min_The_STRIDE.mp4; fi
```

Create an Ubuntu EC2 Instance:
Size: t3.large (2 CPU, 8 GB RAM)
EBS: 30 GB (can be increased as needed)

Connect to EC2 Instance:Connect to the EC2 instance locally using SSH:

```
ssh -i "s3-upload.pem" ubuntu@ec2-54-224-80-214.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

Install youtube-dl and aws cli using command
sudo snap install aws-cli

Provide AWS credentials

```
Configure aws
Access key : {{}}
Password : {{}}
```

Create script.sh File:
Create a script file named script.sh with all the necessary commands.

Copy script.sh to EC2:
Copy the local script.sh file to the EC2 instance using AWS CLI's aws s3 cp

aws s3 cp {{localScriptPath}} {{ec2ScriptPath}}

```
aws s3 cp s3://content-intake-fod247/Content/script.sh script.sh
```

Enable tmux session
tmux

Execute the Script on EC2:
Run the script.sh file on the EC2 instance.

```
chmod +x script.sh
./script.sh > script.log 2>&1
```

View Log Output:
View the logs at various intervals using cat.
cat script.log

**Why need to create script.sh file ?**
We can copy paste the commands in shell windows upto 4020 character, so in file can add upto any character.

**Commands notes**

1. ; used to separate command in a line
2. Echo is used to write messages in the console
3. To capture logs in file while command execution
   script {{filename}}
   script session1.log
4. Read file

   cat {{filename}}
   cat session1.log
5. ls : to view all files in directory
6. clear : clear all command shell window
7. tmux : you can do that and use tmux
   session, if your connection lost, it will download in background
8. sudo dmidecode -t 17 : is used to view memory space information.

These commands can be helpful in managing your video download and upload process and monitoring the logs while executing the script.